# Recommendation system with big un-tagged data set

Tags: algorithm, automation, recommendation-engine

Suppose, there is an e-commerce site with at least a million products falling in different categories, but no tags or categories are specified.
The only information available on each products are the title string of the product, an image and a description.

Now if I were asked to build a recommendation system for this site, what approach should I take?
The `algorithm` and `overview` of the procedure would be enough. At least some clue on what to look for.

Comment: I think you should use words on `title`s, and count them, most of them can be defined as `Tag` of them, then you can specify category from its tags easier ;).

Comment: thanks for your reply! I was thinking of the same procedure, if not all the words maybe last 3-4 of them given there might be a clue on the category.
but matching them against a million untagged title like that would be rather expensive, right? Any idea on any particular algorithm or filtering process?

Comment: For a recommendation engine, I don't agree with the approach given by @shA.t. You should first create a dictionary of your products from one hand and user purchases on other hand. Then you'll need to run a recommendation algorithm like Collaborative Filtering

Comment: I think @elisah comment is more valuable. But for that I said, You can use database tools like ssis ssrs.

Answer (score 1):

So you have, for each user, what products they bought. Now you want to recommend more products for them.

One simple idea is to do a kind of `users who bought X also bought: ...`. For each product you bought (or the most recent), search what users who bought that product bought that you didn't (order by most buys, or most recent buys).

For more complex strategies, look into [Collaborative Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) and [other approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system#Approaches). There are a lot, it's impossible to say what would work best for your case.

Comment: Is there any specific time complexity for such algorithms? also, does the related image(some kind image processing/filtering) of these products could come into play at any point?

Comment: @user3912900 - you could search for related images, sure. That sounds very expensive though. It would be cheaper to search for related text in descriptions I think. The wikipedia page should list complexities, or  they should be easy enough to find.